# How to set the GL_RGBA in this GLSL example?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am creating the following shader in GLSL, who purpose is to blend 2 textures according to the alpha channel of light_text. Unfortunately the alpha channel is always set to 1 (while I am sure my original texture has values varying from 0 to 1)
I saw in another SO question that I need to put the flag GL_RGBA somewhere because it is at GL_RGB by default, but where would I put this in my example?
Here's the code :

```
const vec3 lumCoeff = vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
uniform sampler2D world_tex;
uniform sampler2D light_tex;
uniform float Alpha;
uniform vec3 NewColor;
void main()
{
    vec3 curColor = vec3(texture2D(world_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy ));
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(texture2D(light_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy ));

    float graylvl = dot(curColor , lumCoeff);

    vec3 appliedLight = lightColor + curColor;

    float coeff = texture2D(light_tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy ).a;// <--- equals 1 always

    vec3 color_saturated     = mix(vec3(graylvl), curColor, Alpha);
    gl_FragColor   = vec4( mix(color_saturated + NewColor, appliedLight,  coeff) , 1.0);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere. It's a parameter to [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml), used when the texture is uploaded by the client.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be set outside of the GLSL code in one of your calls to `glTexImage2D`. The third parameter takes the internal format, which should be `GL_RGBA` as well as the 7th parameter which specifies the format of the data you are putting into the texture (the 7th should already be set or you would not get any usable result).

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if it gave good results with GL_RGB you might want to check your texture first. 
If your texture's image was internally a RGBA array, then starting for the second pixel, you'd get noise since the alpha component should have been interpreted as red for the second pixel and so on.